# Calculating the eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Solution: The eigenvalues for $\begin{bmatrix}1.25 & -.75 \\ -.75 & 1.25\end{bmatrix}$ are $2$ and $0.5$. The corresponding eigenvectors are $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

---

Is it okay if I have the values flipped for the first eigenvector? The way I calculated was:

$Ax=2x$

$x(A-2I)=0$

$\begin{bmatrix}5/4 - 8/4 & -3/4 \\ -3/4 & 5/4 - 8/4 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}-3/4  & -3/4 \\ -3/4 & -3/4 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1  & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1  & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$x_1+x_2=0$

$x_1=-x_2$

$x_2$ is a free variable so $x_2 \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ with the eigenvector being: $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: So it's fine if the eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix}-1 // 1\end{bmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix}1 // -1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Any answer such that $x_1=-x_2$ is valid, so yes it's fine. Note that eigenvectors cannot be $0$

Comment: Notice that $Ax=2x\Leftrightarrow x(A-2I)=0$ is wrong as the right-hand side doesn't make any sense. It should be $(A-2I)x=0$.

Comment: Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue. That’s why saying *the* eigenvector that goes with an eigenvalue is strictly speaking incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to fill out the vectors in the middle, but it's correct.

There's no problem in your first eigenvector having different signs between $x_1$ and $x_2$, since both eigenvectors must be linearly independent if the corresponding eigenvalues are different.